# How to set brunch-config in Phoenix project to load correctly react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, brunch, phoenix-framework

I created new Phoenix 1.0.0 project initialized bower file and installed React js and everything was fine until I added react-router. Now I can't rid of following error:

```
ReactRouter.js:2108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PropTypes' of undefined
```

I think that this is related with brunch-config or maybe react-router and ES6, I've spent a lot of time but I could not find a good solution.

This is my current brunch-config:

```
exports.config = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js",
      order: {
        before: [
          /bower_components/,
          /web\/static\/vendor/
        ]
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },
  conventions: {
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
  },
  paths: {
    watched: [
      "deps/phoenix/web/static",
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],
    public: "priv/static"
  },
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      ignore: [/^(web\/static\/vendor)|(bower_components)/]
    }
  },
  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },
  npm: {
    enabled: true
  }
};
```

When I remove `|(bower_components)` from ignored plugins then I'll get following error:

```
ReactRouter.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'React' of undefined
```

When I modify brunch-config and add vendor to conventions like this:

```
conventions: {
  assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/,
  vendor: [/^(web\/static\/vendor)/]
},
```

and add to app.js direct paths to imports:

```
import React from "bower_components/react/react";
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'bower_components/react-router/build/umd/ReactRouter';
```

then it won't load react in react-router module:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react" from "bower_components/react-router/build/umd/ReactRouter"
```

How to set up Phoenix project with React and React-Router?

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": ["luzny"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~0.13.3",
    "react-router": "~0.13.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phoenix-talk/9AuQ_7spSis (not sure if it can help)

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm thinking that it is related more with react-router and ES6, but there is still a chance that I'm doing something wrong in brunch-config.

Comment: @JoséValim I found solution [by replacing brunch with webpack](http://manukall.de/2015/05/01/automatically-building-your-phoenix-assets-with-webpack/)

Comment: That's awesome to hear! That's exactly why we allow you to bring whatever you want, the JS ecosystem is just too fragmented right now.